# Get indices of cutree of hclust

Tags: r, hclust

Its a very basic question, unfortunately I do not know how to ask it.
Lets say I have the following code for clustering using hclust:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
s = cutree(hc,k=2)
```

Lets assume `sort(s)` gives the following result:

```
Alabama Alaska Arizona Delaware Florida
   1     1       1        2       2
```

How can I get `Alabama Alaska Arizona Delaware Florida` in a list without the bottom cluster number getting appended to it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you expect as the output. But does `names(sort(s))` or `as.list(names(sort(s)))` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, that is the thing, I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the names from the vector itself (as mentioned by @AEBilgrau) `names(sort(s))`. Also, in this particular case, the cutree output will be in the order of the labels of the tree, so you could also use `labels(hc)`.